# Struggling with a problem - command handler

Tags: discord.js

I am making a ticket bot but it doesn't response with anything, the terminal don't show any problems and I came to a conclusion that it is because of my command handler. If anyone can help me make this:

```
const { client, Collection, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    name: "new",
    aliases: ["ticket"]
}

console.log("bot is running correctly")
```

(console.log haven't responded with anything)

viable with this command handler:

```
const { prefix } = require('./config.json')


module.exports = (client, aliases, callback) => {
    if (typeof aliases === 'string') {
        aliases = [aliases]
    }

    client.on('message', message => {
        const { content } = message;

        aliases.forEach(alias => {
            const command = `${prefix}${alias}`
            if (content.startsWith(`${command} `) || content === command) {
                callback(message)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

I am not really experienced and any support is appreciated, I've been trying for a hour fixing this. Thank you once again.

Comment: What did you pass as `callback`?

Comment: currently message

Comment: If you would like,  I can send the ticket code if you would need help.

Comment: No, like when executing the main function with the parameters `client`, `alias`, and `callback`, what do you pass as `callback`

Comment: Hello! I just fixed it, the problem was that I put it into the wrong file when I ran node .
It is now working just perfectly, thank you for taking time to answer! Have a great day.